# Shopware - Getting documentCollection in orderRepository

Tags: php, symfony, shopware

I am currently facing a strange behaviour on shopware 6.

What I need is to get order's documents informations when the order is refunded (invoice number & creditNote number).

Here is how I am getting the `documentEntity` in the `orderRepository`:

```
$criteria = new Criteria([$orderId]);
$criteria->addAssociation('lineItems');
$criteria->addAssociation('documents');
$orderObject = $this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $context);
$documents = $orderObject->first()->getDocuments();
```

**Normal behaviour**

When the order state is set to "refunded_partially", `$documents` perfectly contains what it should.

**The problem**

When the order state is set to "refunded", `$documents` is empty and I have no errors in logs.

Maybe I overlooked but I saw no differences between the dump I made on `$orderObject` when it's "refunded" and when it's "refunded_partially".

Does someone have a clue on how to manage this correctly?

Comment: Do you know for sure that there's documents relating to the "refunded" order? As in does the Shopware code remove documents because it's been refunded?

Comment: Yes, I know for sure because when you change the state, you have the possibility to attach the credit_note or the invoice to the cha (this is the one sent to the customer by mail). and As I said, it works when the state is "refunded_partially".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS this one is pretty tricky to do, I recommand you to use a specific event to work with documents. The event is triggered when a document is created for an order (invoice, credit note, etc.)
[Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67137993/12512609)