# Shopware - get Document Generation Events

Tags: php, symfony, events, event-handling, shopware

I need your help about events in Shopware6.
I'd like to know how I can get the event when a ***credit note is created manually through the backend.***

As example, I took this event : **OrderEvents::ORDER_TRANSACTION_WRITTEN_EVENT** which is findable in "/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Order/OrderEvents.php".

I tried to copy the same syntax in my documentSubscriber like this : **DocumentEvents::DOCUMENT_WRITTEN_EVENT** but this event is not findable in "/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Document/...".

So naturally, I am having this error : "***Attempted to load class "DocumentEvents" from namespace "Emakers\TransmissionPlugin\Subscriber". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?***"

I cannot have the correct "use" statement to make this event. I have no clue on which event I can use at this moment, does someone have an idea?

Comment: Probably you need to subscribe to 'document.written' event. just use it as text in `getSubscribedEvents()` method of your subscriber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Valerii Pravoslavnyi said and after some investigation, every entity has a written event you can find in the core. For example in my case, I used : "document.written" and it worked like a charm !